# Identity Server & Web Api

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am trying to resolve the following problem using best practices.

We have an API server, which uses Authorization with JWT token to call our api endpoints. Now we need to develop Multi platform application (Android, iOS, Web) to consume this api.

We are planning to use .net MAUI for Mobile and Blazor for Web application. All these applications will have a common user base.

Also we would like to share api to third parties, and we would like also to put their users in our common user base.

What would be the proper approach to do it ? Should we add Identity server to our Web API project ? Should we create separate Identity Server project which will share userbase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use IdentityServer and also do host it in a separate service is a best practice.

Because otherwise it will be harder to debug and troubleshoot when you mix IdentityServer with other services.